# Source: If $f \in L^2$ , then $\hat{f} \in L^2$ and $2\pi ||f||_{L^2} = ||\hat{f}||_{L^2}$, where $\hat{f}$ is the fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

This claim turned up in one of my lectures, but there was no proof or source for it given (We don't have a textbook for this course). Does anyone have anymore information on this theorem, or an idea where I can learn more about it?

EDIT: Looking at the Wiki article, they say that the following holds
$${\displaystyle \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\|f(x)\|^{2}\,dx=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\|{\widehat {f}}(\xi )\|^{2}\,d\xi }$$

but then go on to say

> A more precise formulation is that if a function is in both L1(R) and
>   L2(R), then its Fourier transform is in L2(R)

What do they mean, "both in $L^2$ and $L^1$" ? The above formula clearly states that if the left side is finite, ie $f$ is in $L^2$, then the right side is finite, ie $\hat{f}$ is in $L^2 $?

EDIT2: I think I get it, it is becuse they have defined the Fourier transform to only be applicable to $L_1$ functions, so they RHS might not exist if $f$ is not in $L_1$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Comment: @CrazyIvan I've added some details to my question, and I would appreciate someone taking a look at it!

Comment: Both in $L^2$ and $L^1$ means that both $f\in L^2$ and $f\in L^1$ are true.

Answer (score 1):

The key step is for everything converging absolutely (thus in $L^1 \cap L^2$) $$\langle \widehat{f}, \widehat{g} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(x) \overline{g(x)}dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y )e^{-2i\pi xy}dy \overline{g(x)}dx\\ =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y )\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i\pi xy} \overline{g(x)}dxdy = \langle f,\overset{\lor}{\widehat{g}}\ \rangle$$

The Fourier inversion theorem is $ g = \overset{\lor}{\widehat{g}}$ , and letting $f = g$ you get the result for $f, \widehat{f} \in L^1 \cap L^2$.

It extends to $f \in L^2$ because the Fourier transform is now unitary $L^1 \cap L^2 \to L^1 \cap  L^2$, thus continuous.